# Watson text to speech latency

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I'm using Watson text to speech service using Node.js. Instead of downloading the audio file I'm using this to stream it:

```
text_to_speech.synthesize(params)
    .pipe(new ogg.Decoder())
    .on('stream', function (opusStream) {
        opusStream.pipe(new opus.Decoder())
            .pipe(new Speaker());
    });
```

It works, but my problem is that there is too much latency, like I hear the sound after 5 or 8 seconds after the request.

Is this normal? Does anyone have an idea to ameliorate my code?
I know that streaming may have some time to load and play but I'm talking about decreasing the latency time.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just download the file? I initially tried the more complicated pipe-streaming method as you are, but finally gave up as none of the npm packages for playing audio were adequate for my non-standard audio stack. In my testing the performance when just downloading and playing the files for every response is nearly seamless even with a 500ms sleep that I put in just for good measure.